# Функция в функции как вызвать

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. увидел подобный код

```
function demo(){
    alert(0);
    this.demo2=function(x){
      alert(x);   
    }    
}
```

как вызвать функцию demo2 за функции demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это называется «ООП в JavaScript». Читайте гугл, если интересно подробнее.

```
var obj = new demo();
obj.demo2( "text" );
```